# Junit test user input with the coffeeMaker exercise

Tags: java, input, junit, output, program-entry-point

This is an exercise created by Sarah Heckman from NY University. It is used in a Coursera course by the university of Minnesota where I came across it. This exercise is found on many GitHub pages.

There is a coffee machine. It has a main class that needs testing with Junit. I would like to be able to test user input/output.
After struggling for more than a day I couldn't work it out. It's not in the Coursera lectures. I didn't found post of anyone else struggling with it. None of the examples here at SF where helping. None of what I have been reading solved the issue.

To simplify the test I thought of first see that the initial inventory is there. That is option 5. So System.in I place 5. Given that to the main method results in a stackoverflow; given it to the mainMenu results in system under test (SUT) being Null.

How can I test user input and output with unit test?

```
public class CoffeeMakerTest {
    
    private CoffeeMaker coffeeMaker;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws RecipeException {
        coffeeMaker = new CoffeeMaker();
    }
    @Test
    public void testMain() {
            
      System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(("5" + System.getProperty("line.separator")).getBytes()));
      
      ByteArrayOutputStream testOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();      
      System.setOut(new PrintStream(testOut));
      
      /*
      * attemp test via main results in java.lang.StackOverflowError
      */
      //String[] args = {};
      //Main.main(args);
      
      /*
      * attemp test via mainMenu results 
      * java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "edu.ncsu.csc326.coffeemaker.CoffeeMaker.checkInventory()" because "edu.ncsu.csc326.coffeemaker.Main.coffeeMaker" is null
      */
      Main.mainMenu();
      
      String inventory = "Coffee: 15" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
             inventory += "Milk: 15" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
             inventory += "Sugar: 15" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
             inventory += "Chocolate: 15" + System.getProperty("line.separator");  
      assertEquals(inventory, testOut.toString());

    }   
}
```

**------**

```
package edu.ncsu.csc326.coffeemaker;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import edu.ncsu.csc326.coffeemaker.exceptions.InventoryException;
import edu.ncsu.csc326.coffeemaker.exceptions.RecipeException;

/**
 * 
 * @author Sarah Heckman
 *
 * Starts the console UI for the CoffeeMaker
 */
public class Main {
    private static CoffeeMaker coffeeMaker;

    /**
     * Prints the main menu and handles user input for 
     * main menu commands.
     */
    public static void mainMenu() {
        System.out.println("1. Add a recipe");
        System.out.println("2. Delete a recipe");
        System.out.println("3. Edit a recipe");
        System.out.println("4. Add inventory");
        System.out.println("5. Check inventory");
        System.out.println("6. Make coffee");
        System.out.println("0. Exit\n");
        
        //Get user input
        try {
            int userInput = Integer.parseInt(inputOutput("Please press the number that corresponds to what you would like the coffee maker to do."));
            
            if (userInput >= 0 && userInput <=6) {
                if (userInput == 1) addRecipe();
                if (userInput == 2) deleteRecipe();
                if (userInput == 3) editRecipe();
                if (userInput == 4) addInventory();
                if (userInput == 5) checkInventory();
                if (userInput == 6) makeCoffee();
                if (userInput == 0) System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number from 0 - 6");
                mainMenu();
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number from 0 - 6");
            mainMenu();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * The add recipe user interface that process user input.
     */
    public static void addRecipe() {
        
        //Read in recipe name
        String name = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the recipe name: ");
        
        //Read in recipe price
        String priceString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the recipe price: $");
                
        //Read in amt coffee
        String coffeeString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of coffee in the recipe: ");
                
        //Read in amt milk
        String milkString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of milk in the recipe: ");
                
        //Read in amt sugar
        String sugarString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of sugar in the recipe: ");
                
        //Read in amt chocolate
        String chocolateString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of chocolate in the recipe: ");
                
        Recipe r = new Recipe();
        try {
            r.setName(name);
            r.setPrice(priceString);
            r.setAmtCoffee(coffeeString);
            r.setAmtMilk(milkString);
            r.setAmtSugar(sugarString);
            r.setAmtChocolate(chocolateString);
            
            boolean recipeAdded = coffeeMaker.addRecipe(r);
            
            if(recipeAdded) {
                System.out.println(name + " successfully added.\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println(name + " could not be added.\n");
            }
        } catch (RecipeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            mainMenu();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Delete recipe user interface that processes input.
     */
    public static void deleteRecipe() {
        Recipe [] recipes = coffeeMaker.getRecipes();
        for(int i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++) {
            if (recipes[i] != null) {
                System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + recipes[i].getName());
            }
        }
        int recipeToDelete = recipeListSelection("Please select the number of the recipe to delete.");
        
        if(recipeToDelete < 0) {
            mainMenu();
        }
        
        String recipeDeleted = coffeeMaker.deleteRecipe(recipeToDelete);
        
        if (recipeDeleted != null) {
            System.out.println(recipeDeleted + " successfully deleted.\n");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Selected recipe doesn't exist and could not be deleted.\n");
        }
        mainMenu();
    }
    
    /**
     * Edit recipe user interface the processes user input.
     */
    public static void editRecipe() {
        Recipe [] recipes = coffeeMaker.getRecipes();
        for(int i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++) {
            if (recipes[i] != null) {
                System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + recipes[i].getName());
            }
        }
        int recipeToEdit = recipeListSelection("Please select the number of the recipe to edit.");
        
        if(recipeToEdit < 0) {
            mainMenu();
        }
        
        //Read in recipe price
        String priceString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the recipe price: $");
        
        //Read in amt coffee
        String coffeeString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of coffee in the recipe: ");
        
        //Read in amt milk
        String milkString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of milk in the recipe: ");
        
        //Read in amt sugar
        String sugarString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of sugar in the recipe: ");
        
        //Read in amt chocolate
        String chocolateString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of chocolate in the recipe: ");
        
        Recipe newRecipe = new Recipe();
        try {
            newRecipe.setPrice(priceString);
            newRecipe.setAmtCoffee(coffeeString);
            newRecipe.setAmtMilk(milkString);
            newRecipe.setAmtSugar(sugarString);
            newRecipe.setAmtChocolate(chocolateString);
            
            String recipeEdited = coffeeMaker.editRecipe(recipeToEdit, newRecipe);
            
            if (recipeEdited != null) {
                System.out.println(recipeEdited + " successfully edited.\n");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(recipeEdited + "could not be edited.\n");
            }
        } catch (RecipeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            mainMenu();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Add inventory user interface that processes input.
     */
    public static void addInventory() {
        //Read in amt coffee
        String coffeeString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of coffee to add: ");
                
        //Read in amt milk
        String milkString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of milk to add: ");
                
        //Read in amt sugar
        String sugarString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of sugar to add: ");
                
        //Read in amt chocolate
        String chocolateString = inputOutput("\nPlease enter the units of chocolate to add: ");
                
        try {
            coffeeMaker.addInventory(coffeeString, milkString, sugarString, chocolateString);
            System.out.println("Inventory successfully added");
        } catch (InventoryException e) {
            System.out.println("Inventory was not added");
        } finally {
            mainMenu();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Check inventory user interface that processes input.
     */
    public static void checkInventory() {
        System.out.println(coffeeMaker.checkInventory());
        mainMenu();
    }
    
    /**
     * Make coffee user interface the processes input.
     */
    public static void makeCoffee() {
        Recipe [] recipes = coffeeMaker.getRecipes();
        for(int i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++) {
            if (recipes[i] != null) {
                System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + recipes[i].getName());
            }
        }
        
        int recipeToPurchase = recipeListSelection("Please select the number of the recipe to purchase.");
        
        String amountPaid = inputOutput("Please enter the amount you wish to pay");
        int amtPaid = 0;
        try {
            amtPaid = Integer.parseInt(amountPaid);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer");
            mainMenu();
        }
        
        int change = coffeeMaker.makeCoffee(recipeToPurchase, amtPaid);
        
        if (change == amtPaid) {
            System.out.println("Insufficient funds to purchase.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thank you for purchasing " + coffeeMaker.getRecipes()[recipeToPurchase].getName());
        }
        System.out.println("Your change is: " + change + "\n");
        mainMenu();
    }
    
    /**
     * Passes a prompt to the user and returns the user specified 
     * string.
     * @param message
     * @return String
     */
    private static String inputOutput(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String returnString = "";
        try {
            returnString = br.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error reading in value");
            mainMenu();
        }
        return returnString;
    }
    
    /**
     * Passes a prompt to the user that deals with the recipe list
     * and returns the user selected number.
     * @param message
     * @return int
     */
    private static int recipeListSelection(String message) {
        String userSelection = inputOutput(message);
        int recipe = 0;
        try {
            recipe = Integer.parseInt(userSelection) - 1;
            if (recipe >= 0 && recipe <=2) {
                //do nothing here.
            } else {
                recipe = -1;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please select a number from 1-3.");
            recipe = -1;
        }
        return recipe;
    }
    
    /**
     * Starts the coffee maker program.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        coffeeMaker = new CoffeeMaker();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the CoffeeMaker!\n");
        mainMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is untestable without the help of some library that allows mocking of static fields. If it's not an exercises, i wouldn't even bother writing tests for such non-object-oriented code. Or try to rewrite it in object-oriented style, use a dependency on some interface that would take user input and give your object as a dependency a stubbed mock created with Mockito(or some other library).